# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Event Not Fired When Modal is Shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

According to the docs:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

It should fire the methods "show.bs.dropdown" and "shown.bs.dropdown". But it doesn't:

http://jsfiddle.net/mQunq/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">Hello world</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
// show.bs.modal doesn't work either

$('#myModal')
    .modal('show')
    .on('show.bs.modal', function() {

        alert('shown baby!');

    });
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Youe need first register event then trigger  it

```
$('#myModal')
    .on('show.bs.modal', function() {

        alert('shown baby!');

    }).modal('show');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQunq/4/)

Comment: Ahh ok makes sense. I didn't know I had to register it myself, I thought the core plugin triggered it. I think that's the way it used to work with the previous version.

Comment: This answer needs more attention. I ran into a similar issue of forcing a modal open based on some conditions. Took me a bit of digging to find out this was the way to do it.

Comment: Agree with @Shaazaam - there must be a dozen or so answers on stackoverflow that have not addressed the registration and triggering requirement.

Comment: Also note that the modal is not supposed to be shown at the moment of triggering the _show.bs.modal_ event. The correct event to be handled is _show**n**.bs.modal_. The latter one waits for CSS transitions to finish.

Answer (score 11):

## When it happens

Event **shown**.bs.modal is not fired when modal has also class "fade". Whereas **show**.bs.modal always works.
See  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11793

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="first" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">Hello world from first modal</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="second" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">Hello world from second modal</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    //fired only in second modal
    console.info('shown.bs.modal');
});

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    //fired always
    console.info('show.bs.modal');
});
```

## Solution

For bootstrap v3.3.6 replace line 1010 with:

```
that.$element // wait for modal to slide in
```

### What is the problem

Look at lines 1006-1015:

```
  var e = $.Event('shown.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })

  transition ?
    that.$dialog // wait for modal to slide in
      .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
        that.$element.trigger('focus').trigger(e)
      })
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
    that.$element.trigger('focus').trigger(e)
```

Without transition (no *fade* class) the event *e* is triggered right away (on that.$element).
With transition, I'm not sure why exactly, but somehow the *bsTransationEnd* event from function *emulateTransitionEnd* is not handled by *that.$dialog.one()*. But with *that.$element*, everything seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Similar thing happened to me and I have solved using setTimeout.

Bootstrap is using the following timeout to complete showing:

> c.TRANSITION_DURATION=300,c.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION=150,

So using more than 300 must work and for me 200 is working:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Do something if necessary
    }, 300);                        
})
```

Comment: @ShellZero 150 - depends on what's the fade-in/fade-out time for the modal. By default it's 150 ms. For safety I'd use 160 ms for `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the "n" on shown

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal')
.modal('show')
.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

    alert('shown baby!');

});

});
```

Comment: Both are events. `show.bs.modal` fires immediately; `shown.bs.modal` fires after the modal has faded in.

Answer (score 1):

Use document instead of your custom selector. Both shown.bs.modal and show.bs.modal work just fine

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    alert();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this problem, make sure you hook the on `hidden` / `shown` event **before** firing the `toggle` of the modal. That is, declare this:

```
$("#selector").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    // do the right thing
});
```

Before calling the toggle of the modal, e.g.:

```
("#selector").modal("toggle");
```

I know this is basic, but in a convoluted code it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works with `.fade` transitions:

```
$(document).on($.support.transition.end, '.modal.fade.in', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($(e.target).is(".modal-dialog")) {
    console.log("Modal Shown")
  }
});

$(document).on($.support.transition.end, '.modal.fade', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if (!$target.is(".modal.fade.in") && !$target.is(".modal-dialog")) {
    console.log("Modal Hidden")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your modal is *dynamically* created, select the closest static parent element and add your modal as a parameter for bootstrap modal events to work:

```
/* body is static, .modal is not */

$("body").on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {

    alert('shown');

});


$("body").on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {

    alert('hidden');

});


$("body").on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {

    alert('show');

});


$("body").on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {

    alert('hide');

});
```